# What is the magnitude of dot product of two vectors?

Tags: calculus

This was the question (or rather to prove) given by our professor: $|(a.c)| \leq |a||c|$ where $a$ and $c$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. My friend and I solved it in two different ways and now we don't know who is correct.
$a=\{x,y,z\}$ and $c=\{d,e,f\}$  to find $|\{x,y,x\}.\{d,e,f\}|$.

My approach: $\sqrt{(xd)^2 + (ye)^2 + (zf)^2}$

My friend's: $\sqrt{(xd+ye+zf)^2}$

Which one is correct? Thank You!
(Bear with me if i am wrong with brackets... 'a' and 'c' are vectors.)

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is a scalar, you do not calculate its magnitude like you calculate the length of a vector, you just calculate its magnitude by taking the absolute value. Your friend is technically correct albeit really by coincidence (I don't think s/he understands how s/he got that answer).

Comment: Although the friend's calculation does look like the absolute value of the dot product... Just a bit more complicated that necessary.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, you meant $|\langle x, y, \color{red}{z} \rangle \cdot \langle d, e, f \rangle|$.

Comment: Just a comment: The inequality you (Nisarg Patel) are talking about is called "Cauchy-Schwarz inequality".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$\displaystyle \vec{a}\cdot \vec{c}=|\vec{a}||\vec{c}|\cos \theta \leq |\vec{a}||\vec{c}|$$

Now Let $$\vec{a} = <x,y,z>$$ and $$\vec{c}=<d,e,f>$$

So Using above formula $$(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c})\leq |\vec{a}||\vec{c}|\Rightarrow (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c})^2\leq |\vec{a}|^2|\vec{c}|^2$$

So we get $$(xd+ye+zf)^2\leq (x^2+y^2+z^2)(d^2+e^2+f^2)$$

So $$(xd+ye+zf)\leq \sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(d^2+e^2+f^2)}$$